# Yast sources for Suse EL 10.2

Tags: linux, suse

I am using Suse EL 10.2 on IBM cloud, and need to install basic packages such as gcc, zlib, etc.
Is there any official Suse 10 sources that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either download the rpm's directly from Novell and install them manually or use Novell's SMT server, as far as supported packages go.